# Add keywords to listings in preamble or lstlang1.sty

Tags: listings, highlighting, keywords

## Some keywords I want to add

I would like to add a few keywords for C, but am having difficulty. The keywords I would like to include are `bool`, `simd`, `omp`, `restrict`, etc. I would like these to be just for the C language.

## Editing the style directly

I would like to 'update' these to the language style definition in the document's preamble, but there doesn't seem a nice interface to this. My current solution is to directly adjust the settings in
`/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty`
where I add them to the `ANSI C` definition around line 251 by adding these to the the `morekeywords` and `otherkeywords` such as:

```
\lst@definelanguage[ANSI]{C}{%
morekeywords={auto,break,...etc...,volatile,while,omp,simd,restrict},%
otherkeywords={\#pragma},% <-- Added to catch indented #pragma
...
}
```

This gives the desired output

[image]

for

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#pragma omp simd
void foo(int * restrict a, int n, int n_simd)
{
    #pragma omp simd
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] *= 2; /* Computation */
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

## Can something be put in the pramble?

Ultimately I would like something more portable that can just be put in the document's preamble, but the following attempts haven't succeeded:

```latex
\lstset{otherkeywords={\#pragma,omp,simd}}
```

```latex
\lstdefinestyle{C}{morekeywords={restrict}}
```

```latex
\lstset{%
    language={C},%
    morekeywords={auto,...
...
}
```

## New environment/language/style

Preferably I would rather avoid creating a new language or style such as `myC` or similar, and would prefer just declaring `language=C` as this seems better practice and avoids having to refactor my code.

## Related questions

- [Undesirable highlighting of a keyword name (dh) occuring within an
  identifier (0dh)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28431/106804)
- [Prevent LaTeX listings from highlighting part of
  word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432232/106804)
- [Adding Keywords to Existing Language for Listings Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224093/106804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can define a custom style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{C}{
language=C,
morekeywords={omp,simd,restrict},
otherkeywords={\#pragma}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=C]
#pragma omp simd
void foo(int * restrict a, int n, int n_simd)
{
    #pragma omp simd
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] *= 2; /* Computation */
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know if I can achieve this outcome but somehow set this as the default style of the C language, so as to avoid having to refactor all my code to include `style=C`, as stating both `language=C` and `style=C` seems to be saying the same thing twice.

Comment: I updated my answer, so you can use only style. But as i understand you can't redefine the language.

Comment: That should work, so long as I only have to declare it once. Will test it shortly.